# Android activity not found exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest

I am receiving this erro message in my logcat:

```
10-19 21:00:08.672: E/AndroidRuntime(808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 21:00:08.672: E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.minyanapp.activities/com.minyanapp.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.minyanapp.activities.SplashActivity
```

also, before the above message I get this error:

```
10-19 22:07:13.003: E/Trace(1157): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Here is my Manifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.minyanapp.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.minyanapp.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.minyanapp.activities.Dummy"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dummy" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried to delete gen and bin folders, restart eclipse and emulator. Nothing helped.

Help please!!!

Comment: is the folder structure for the file correct as com.minyanapp.activities.SplashActivity?

Comment: Yes, it is in src->com.minyanapp.activities (package).

Comment: @VladIoffe : Have you tried Project -> Clean in eclipse?

Comment: @Squonk yes... for few times :(

Comment: I have added some information, I am getting `10-19 22:07:13.003: E/Trace(1157): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
` also.

Comment: Can you post both of your activities? At least only the activity with the `onCreate` method.

Comment: I have created a new lunch activity and deleted the old one, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to delete the project and copy all classes, layouts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just reproduced the problem on my machine. Here is what I did :

In file `MyAndroid\bin\AndroidManifest.xml` my class is `com.example.myandroid.MainActivity`.
While in `MyAndroid\AndroidManifest.xml` my class is `com.example.myandroid.LunchActivity`

Then I get :

```
10-19 21:21:15.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myandroid/com.example.myandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myandroid.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.myandroid-1.apk
```

**Changing both Manifest.xmls would resolve the issue.**

Comment: Make sure both manifest xmls have SplashActivity as the main action

Comment: Both have SplashActivity as the main action

Comment: @GV : The copy of AndroidManifest.xml in the /bin directory is put there by the build process. There is never a need to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In splashactivitie.java the first line of code is package com.minyanapp.activities ; right? The class file splasplashactivites.class is in the bin folder,right? Meaning it is compiling, probably is if you got logcat message.

Comment: there is now splashactivities.class file in bin folder.